# Prompt message in Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++, nppexec

I started using Notepad++ 5.1. with NppExec 0.4.3.2 Unicode plugin.
I need it for practicing python.

What I noticed is that NppExec (or even Notepad) itself is a bit buggy.
For some reason, this code:

```
word = raw_input("type something")
print len(word)
```

Always outputs the len()+1 value.
For example, if I enter: "python" after the raw_input prompt, it prints: 7 instead of 6.
Why is that so?

Thank you.

Comment: almost willing to bet somewhere a `'\n'` is getting added along for the ride. personally i use np++ but for executing stuff, i use the PyNPP plugin, as it can load something up in an interactive python session, and you can directly check if thats whats going on.

Comment: Thank you for the reply TehTris.
I just started learning programming (with not prior knowledge of it), so installing the NppExec was a hell of job. I am afraid it might be the same situation with the PyNPP too?

Would you be so kind to tell where should I take a look for that "\n"?

Comment: no problem. type your code in np++ and then go to plugins-> PyNPP -> Run file in python interactive. Then a python window will pop up. it will say `"type something"` , then you will type `"python"` and hit enter. THEN if `len(word)` is `6`, you know its correct. if `len(word)` is `7`, then just type `"word"`, and it will display EXACTLY what `'word'` is.

Comment: There is no PyNPP in my Plugins drop menu

Comment: you have to install it, go to plugin manager and find it